# Vue CLI is giving error ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, vuejs3

I am taking my first steps with Vuex and I am trying to implement some API requests using it.

I have implemented the following structure:

Component.Vue

```js
export default {
  created() {
     this.$store.dispatch('getData', {value: this.$route.params.title});
  },
}
```

VueX Store (this is the action that handles the mutation which makes the api call.)

```js
actions: {
    getData(context, payload) {
       context.commit('getData', payload);
    },
},
```

Everything works as expected, content gets fetched from the API and it is rendered on the page. But if I open DevTools, each and every X seconds, a Time Out Error Appears. It says this:

> **sockjs.js?9be2:1606 GET http://192.168.0.00:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1607010077338 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT**

Do you have any clue about what am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Regards,
T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be an issue with the Vue CLI (webpack) `devServer` hostname.  Try this in *vue.config.js*:

```js
module.exports = {
   devServer: {
      host: 'localhost'
   }
};
```

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it helped.  Vue CLI uses Webpack devServer to serve your app locally, which uses *sockjs-node* for HMR (hot module reload).  I think this error is due to a discrepancy between the request and response domain, one using `localhost` and the other using an IP address